# Can't get bootstrap columns to work the way I want it to

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am trying to a section on the page so that there is 2 sets of an image and words on each row when the screen is in lg and md modes.

so it should go something like this...
(img) (words...)  (img)(words...)
(img) (words...)  (img)(words...)

```
<div class="container rowSpacing">
            <h1 class="text-center">We Capture All Memories...</h1>
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="images/NewLogo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <h2>Your loved ones...</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="images/NewLogo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <h2>Your special day...</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="images/NewLogo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <h2>Your last moments...</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="images/NewLogo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <h2>Your beautiful moments...</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: that's what it looks like to me? maybe I'm misunderstanding the end goal/problem. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LWzdax

Comment: Thanks everyone!..Slowly but surely learning this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

and setting each of your columns to a set height

Comment: Thank you David! Sometimes I feel dumb when it's something as simple as that

Comment: No worries, I have spent a lot of time banging my head against the wall dealing with css.  Can be very confusing at times.  If this was your solution  please mark the answer as correct, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container rowSpacing">
            <h1 class="text-center">We Capture All Memories...</h1>



            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="images/NewLogo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <h2>Your loved ones...</h2>
                </div>



                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="images/NewLogo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <h2>Your special day...</h2>
                </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="images/NewLogo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <h2>Your last moments...</h2>
                </div>



                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="images/NewLogo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <h2>Your beautiful moments...</h2>
                </div>

  </div>

            </div>
```

[sample code](http://www.bootply.com/whPN3tRNG2)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the `clearfix` DIV after the second and after the sixth pair of image+texts:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aJLYeZ

Comment: I am not getting the same results as you are. It still looks all jumbled up.